# Get Substring from Json Value using Grep

Tags: json, grep, substring

I have such json file:

```
{
  "fruits": [
   {
     "name": "apple",
     "type": "gala",
     "product_id": "PA:app-1d39gsg",
     "in_stock": "Y"
   }
  ] 
}
```

From this file, I want to get only this `app-id39gsg` using grep.

Tried

```
grep -o 'app-*' test.json
```

but doesn't work.

How do I get that substring from json data?

I would appreciate your advice.

Comment: grep doesn't understand JSON, use a proper parser such as [tag:jq]

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your string always starts with `PA:`.

```
jq -r '.fruits[].product_id | sub("^PA:";"")' file.json
```

Output:

```
app-1d39gsg
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use only grep or can you use other common Linux tools as well?

Here's a suggestion using grep + sed:

```
grep -o 'app-\S*' text.json | sed 's/..$//'
```

**Output:**

```
app-1d39gsg
```

**Explaining:**

- `grep` matches anything starting from "app-"
- `sed` removes the last two characters

**Note:** This assumes you're using an implementation of `grep` which supports flag `-o`, like GNU grep does. You should be able to check your version with `grep --version`.

Comment: Awk can do all that alone. Besides, those are not Linux tools, and only a few grep implementations support `-o` option and `\S` pattern.

Comment: Also, I agree `awk` most likely can do all that alone, but since I don't have the knowledge to write such a command I wrote something that works combining a few tools.

Comment: Or everything in jq: `.fruits[].product_id | split(":")[1]`

Comment: That's a great suggestion if he can use `jq`. I agree it's the best/cleanest option.